# Why does this test class not cover these lines

Tags: unit-test

The bold lines are the lines that are not covered. 
**Controller**

```
public class GHI_Portal_Password_Controller {

    public Boolean hasNewPassword { get; set; }
    public Boolean hasSecurity { get;set; }
    public Boolean isReset {get;set;}
    public Boolean hasConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public String newPassword { get; set; }
    public String confirmPassword { get; set; }
    public String passwordMsg { get; set; }
    public String securityError { get; set; }

    public String charAllowed { get; set; }

    public User currentUser { get; set; }
    public Boolean passwordMatch{get;set;}


    public GHI_Portal_Password_Controller(){
        this.charAllowed = Label.GHI_Portal_AllowedChar;
        this.hasConfirmPassword = true;
        this.hasNewPassword = true;
        passwordMsg = '';
        passwordMatch= false; 
        currentUser = [Select GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c,GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c,GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c,
                                GHI_Portal_Answer_1__c,GHI_Portal_Answer_2__c, GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        // system.debug('@@currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c '+currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c);
        if ((currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c != '') && 
            (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c != '') &&  
            (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c != '') &&
            (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_1__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_1__c != '') &&
            (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_2__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_2__c != '') &&
            (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c != null && currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c != ''))
            {
            isReset = false;
        } 
        else{
            isReset = true;
        }                    
    }


    public PageReference changePasswordPage() {
    PageReference prSiteChangePass;
    this.passwordMsg='';


            if (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c == null || currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_1__c==null ||
                currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c == null || currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_2__c==null ||
                currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c == null || currentUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c==null) {
                hasSecurity = true;
                this.securityError = Label.GHI_Portal_SecurityError;
            }
            **else if(newPassword.length() > 20 || confirmPassword.length() > 20) {
                    this.passwordMsg = Label.GHI_Portal_PasswordMsg;
                    passwordMatch = true;**
                    //return ApexPages.currentPage();
            }
            **else if (newPassword.contains(' ')) {
                this.passwordMsg = Label.GHI_Portal_PasswordMsg;**
                //System.debug('@@passwordMsg2 ' + passwordMsg);
                **passwordMatch = true;**
                //return ApexPages.currentPage();
            } 
            **else if (currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c == currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c ||**
                        currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c == currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c ||
                        currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c == currentUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c) {
                        **hasSecurity = true;
                this.securityError = Label.GHI_Portal_UniqueQuestionMsg;**
            }
            else{
                **update currentUser;
                prSiteChangePass = Site.changePassword(newPassword, confirmPassword);
                return ((hasNewPassword && hasConfirmPassword) ? prSiteChangePass : ApexPages.currentPage());** 
            }
            return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class GHI_Portal_Password_Controller_Test {

    private static testMethod void test() {

    }
    private static testMethod void testLogin() {
        GHI_Portal_Password_Controller controller1 = new GHI_Portal_Password_Controller();
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.Username= 'testUser11@company.com';
        testUser.Email = 'testuser1@company.com';
        testUser.Lastname = 'user';
        testUser.Firstname = 'test';
        testUser.Alias = 'test';
        testUser.CommunityNickname = '12346test';
        List<Profile> prof = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
        List<UserRole> role =  [select Id from UserRole where Name = 'finance'];
        testUser.UserRoleId = role[0].Id;
        testUser.ProfileId = prof[0].Id;

        //testUser.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        testUser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
        testUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        testUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';

        testUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        testUser.UserPermissionsMobileUser = false;
        insert testUser;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.GHI_Portal_Login;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('A','1');
        GHI_Portal_Login controller = new GHI_Portal_Login();
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            RecordType rtContact = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='Contact' AND Name='Patient' LIMIT 1];
            Account acct = OSM_DataFactory.createAccount('test test');
            insert acct;
            Contact ctct = OSM_DataFactory.createContact('test','test',rtContact.Id);
            ctct.AccountId = acct.Id;
            insert ctct;

            User user = new User();
            user.Username= 'testUser1@company.com';
            user.Email = 'testuser1@company.com';
            user.Lastname = 'user';
            user.Firstname = 'test';
            user.Alias = 'test';
            user.CommunityNickname = '12346';
            List<Profile> prof1 = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'GHI Portal User' LIMIT 1];
            user.ProfileId = prof1[0].Id;
            user.ContactId = ctct.Id;

            //testUser.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
            user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
            user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
            user.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
            user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
            user.UserPermissionsMobileUser = false;
            user.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c ='';
            user.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c ='';
            user.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c ='';  
            user.GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c = '';
            insert user;
            controller1.changePasswordPage();
            controller1.newPassword = 'dsadsadsada';
            controller1.confirmPassword = 'dsadadasda';
            update user;
            update testUser;
            update acct;
            update ctct;
            Test.stopTest();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please point out which line numbers? The formatting isn't showing bold lines here.

Comment: the lines with ** text here ** i dont know why it didnt become bold sorry 
I use cntrl + b

Comment: You're not specifying those GHI portal security question and answer fields on the `testUser` record, so they're always going to be null, which means the first `IF` statement will always evaluate to true and the code will never get to the rest of the `ELSE IF` blocks.

Comment: how can i do that sir? can you help me with the codes sorry im new at apex coding and test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the field values on your test record that you're inserting to match against your logic in your controller. Roughly it should look something like this below. With small modifications you'll make it work, this is just to give you an idea of how your test classes should work. Also make sure you use asserts to ensure your code behaves as expected.

After this line in your existing code:

```
controller1.changePasswordPage();
```

Add the following:

```
// Set your values in these fields so it doesn't go in the first IF statement
testUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_1__c = 'Test';
testUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_2__c = 'Test';
testUser.GHI_Portal_Security_Question_3__c = 'Test';
testUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_1__c = 'Test';
testUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_2__c = 'Test';
testUser.GHI_Portal_Answer_3__c = 'Test';
update testUser;
controller1 = new GHI_Portal_Password_Controller(); // re-initialise the controller in order to get the field values in the user variable
// Also set newPassword and confirmPassword with length > 20 so that it executes the 2nd else-if block
controller1.newPassword = '1234567890123456789012345';
controller1.confirmPassword = '1234567890123456789012345';
controller1.changePasswordPage(); // Call again this method, this time it should skip the first IF statement since it evaluates to false
// Let's now change the passwords again so that it doesn't go in the 2nd but goes in the 3rd else-if (means we have to have whitespace in the password)
controller1.newPassword = 'a b';
controller1.confirmPassword = 'a b';
controller1.changePasswordPage();
// Reset all this again so that all first 3 if/else-if blocks are skipped (< 20 characters and no whitespace)
controller1.newPassword = 'abc';
controller1.confirmPassword = 'abc';
controller1.changePasswordPage();
// Update the question/answer values again just like for the 1st if statement, but make sure they all have different values so that your last else if is covered
```

I haven't tested this, as I mentioned above it's just to point you to the right direction.